# (2)No such file or directory: mod_wsgi (pid=24507)

Tags: django, ubuntu, mod-wsgi

I have an a few Django apps running on Ubuntu Precise and Ubuntu Lucid.
I've noticed that sometimes in my logs I've got a few 503's. During those 503's I've found these logs in my apache error logs:

> (2) `No such file or directory: mod_wsgi (pid=24507): Unable to connect to WSGI daemon process 'appname' on '/var/run/apache2/wsgi.27607.2.18.sock' after multiple attempts`

All of my apps have WSGIDaemon mode set with similar setting to this:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess appname display-name=wsgi-appname \
        processes=4 \
        threads=4 \
        maximum-requests=1000 \
        inactivity-timeout=120 \
        deadlock-timeout=60 \
        shutdown-timeout=5
WSGIProcessGroup appname
```

The mod_wsgi docs have reference to this issue here: https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationIssues#Location_Of_UNIX_Sockets
But that doesn't seem to apply to my situation since I only see the error occasionally.

An interesting thing to note:
On my one server apache was started March 12th. The last time I saw an error was `Mar 25 18:02:32`, which matches the create date of the `.sock` file.
Edit: this timestamp updates when an apache reload happens. I wonder if the reload is causing the 503s...

Does anyone know why this is happening or how I can debug it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. An Apache graceful restart can cause this, especially where HTTP clients are using keep alive connections. If you are running just a Python web application with mod_wsgi daemon mode and not using Apache for anything else, since the graceful restart doesn't do anything special for mod_wsgi daemon processes, you may just as well use Apache restart instead of reload.

For a more in-depth description of how mod_wsgi works, use the mod_wsgi list and not StackOverflow as here is not a discussion forum.